# Possible code for active div

Tags: php, css, function

In `logged.php`:

```
$TPL->NavBar('active',' ');
```

In `class.template.php`:

```
public function NavBar($home,$about) {
    $this->Content('navigator_bar');            
}
```

In `navigator_bar.php`:

```
<li class= <?php $home ?> ><a href="home">Home</a></li>
<li class= <?php $about ?> ><a href="about">About</a></li>
```

Is that possible to link `$home` and `$about` variables into a new `file.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use request methods such as $_GET,$_POST,[$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) to send data to your new_file.php

or

set the variables in session to get it in your new_file.php

**IN SESSION:**

> In Logged.php:

```
echo $_SESSION['home_val'] = $home;
echo $_SESSION['about']    = $about;
```

> In new_file.php:

```
$_SESSION['home_val'];//gives $home

$_SESSION['about'];//gives $about
```